# Validate multiple checked Checkbox

Tags: forms, scala, validation, playframework-2.0

is there a way to validate multiple checked checkboxes properly? 
How are the data been sent?
Something like eyeColor[0] = blue?

```
<form action="send" method="POST" id="send-form">
 <input type="checkbox" id="eyeColor" name="eyeColor[]" value="blue">
 <input type="checkbox" id="eyeColor" name="eyeColor[]" value="brown">
 <input type="checkbox" id="eyeColor" name="eyeColor[]" value="green">
</form>


"eyeColor" -> seq(text.verifying(enum(eyeColor().keySet.map(_.toString), "error.searchProfile.eyeColor")))
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you get `eyeColor` as a `List[String]`, as if it was a multiple select. You can not see the ones that are not selected (they're not passed in the http request).

Comment: Found a solution.
The checked checkboxes are sent as comma separated string values.
Every single value needs to be validated to validate the "checkbox group".

The case class:

    case class Registration(
      eyeColor: String,
     )

The Controller:

    def form() = Form(
        mapping(
          "eyeColor" -> text.verifying(eyeColors, "error.eyeColor"))
        )(Registration.apply)(Registration.unapply)
    )